# Full Screen Mode of Android Gallery

Tags: android

Do Android Gallery have full screen mode(I mean after clicking on the image of galley I will get the full screen gallery)?

Comment: It will have it if you make it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android Open Source Project is your friend. You can make your own build of the stock Android Gallery app and implement this feature yourself.

Have fun.

http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html

Comment: It's easily to do this feature using two activities but someone prefer to down rate instead of only to think a little about the problem.